# How can I find chain of factorial of large number in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

if number is `3!!` should result `6!` that is `720`.
This code works for small integers but throws error `Python int too large to convert to C long` for large integers. Need help. Thanks

```
import math
n = raw_input()
a = n.count('!')
b= int(n.replace('!',''))
while(a!=0):
    fact =1*math.factorial(b)
    b = fact
    a-=1
print fact
```

Comment: Seems like `math.factorial` can only handle C-integers. Should not be too hard to implement your own factorial function, though. (But that may be a bad idea, since if the input number is already that large those calculations could take _very_ long).

Comment: why do you multiply the factorial by 1? you can replace the while loop with a ranged for.

Comment: Tried it, much better than before. Now throws run-time error for large integers. I think, I should go with numpy.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do this. The result for large numbers (above 10 or so) would take billions of digits. How would you print it?

Answer (score 0):

if math.factorial doesn't support such big numbers you can do it yourself:

```
    fact = reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [x+1 for x in range(b)])

    >>> 4!!
    620448401733239439360000
```

however, @interjay is correct, math.factorial() should work for numbers up to 8 in reasonable time.  Regardless, the algorithm should be correct, it just may never come back or run out of memory for large numbers.

Comment: Sure, `math.factorial(24)` is not a problem, but try `100!!` or similar. However, as noted in comments, this will just put the problem someplace else: The resulting number would take ages to calculate and would have billions of digits.